# TrimmingText для TextBlock с MultiBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Не получается решить проблему. У меня есть TextBlock, который показывает имя файла и расширение. Ест модель данных, в которой есть поле FileName и Extension. Используя MultiBinding я вывожу данные в TextBlock. Но есть проблема. У TextBlock проставлено свойство TextTrimming для обрезки текста. Как и следует, блок обрезается следующим образом : `Это текстовый ф...`
Но мне необходима обрезка следующего вида: `Это текстовый ф....txt`. Подскажите, как подступиться к решению проблемы?

Текущий xaml-код:

```
<TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}{1}">
            <Binding Path="FileName" />
            <Binding Path="Extension" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Например, написать конвертер и триммить что хотите и как хотите

Comment: @tym32167, а как тогда тримить строку в конвертере?

Comment: в смысле как? Смотреть на длину строки. и если она длинная, то вызывать substring

Comment: @tym32167, как понять длинная? У меня TextBlock не фиксированной ширины, плюс нет конкретного FontSize(FontSize погружается из динамического стиля). Как определить , что строка не влезает, и как в конвертере определить, сколько именно надо обрезать?

Comment: не совсем по теме, но, возможно, вам поможет Viewbox?

Comment: ну так передавайте в конвертер всю нужную инфу, ширину контрола, шрифт, всё, что вам надо и считайте

Comment: ну или как выторой вариант, использовать  2 текстбокса, первый с триммингом, а второй с раширением

Comment: @ValeryLosev, решение надо постить ответом, а не править вопрос